# NFC-enabled smartphones: App or not?

Tags: nfc

Can someone please help me to better understand how NFC-enabled smartphones work?  Is it controlled by an app on the smartphone or by the device itself?

Thanks!

Comment: This question is clear. As mud. **What** is controlled by the app or the device? The radio electronics required for NFC?

Comment: Questions about **general computing hardware and software** are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/).

Answer (score 2):

NFC stands for Near Field Communication. Apps control the NFC chip/antenna that is built in the phone. So a phone without the NFC hardware, could never have an NFC app work on it. So you do need both in order for it to work.

Basically think of NFC just like bluetooth, only that NFC has an effective range of around 4-5cm and not any further.

I think this like might help: http://www.androidauthority.com/how-it-works-nfc-near-field-communication-97144/

If there is anything else specifically that you don't understand, please say so.